# Upgrade container for long running jobs in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have long running workers running in kubernetes - more than 5 hours. I want to update the container without interrupting the long running jobs. I want any newly started work off the queue to start with the new version of the release but I don't want to interrupt the currently running work.

BTW I'm not actually using Jobs, I'm using Deployments with workers that get work off a redis queue.

What is the best way to do to do a release without killing the long running work?

1. Have a huge timeout for SIGTERM
2. preStop hooks?
3. Another container in the pod that checks for the latest version and updates once work is done?

Comment: Hi @Costi, could you explain me, what exactly do you mean by update? I suppose it will be helpful [blue-green update](https://codefresh.io/kubernetes-tutorial/blue-green-deploy/) Do you want to terminate your container after update?

Comment: We are actually facing a similar problem. We have long-running operations, but we are not yet running them as jobs, but running them inside regular pods (managed by a deployment). These long-running operations are not fully under our control, so we cannot know when (and if) they terminate, but the common mechanism like setting a long "terminationGracePeriodSeconds" seem not to be the right way - in particular since we would have to set this to at least a few hours. We are investigating to build an operator that "drains" our pods of long-running tasks and juggles with PDBs to let them finish.